# Склоняется ли фамилия Покинь-Соха?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Я устал искать ответ, склоняется моя фамилия или нет - **Покинь-Соха**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Составные фамилии склоняются в зависимости от структуры. Если это сочетание двух фамилий, которые воспринимаются как самостоятельные, то склоняются обе части  -  картина Петрова-Водкина. Если первая часть не употребляется по отдельности, то она не склоняется: Бонч-Бруевич - Бонч-Бруевича, Тулуз-Лотрек -  Тулуз-Лотреку.

В вашем случае склоняется вторая часть - соха.

> Им.п.Покинь-Соха
>
> Р.п. Покинь-Сохи
>
> Д.п. Покинь-Сохе
>
> В.п. Покинь-Соху
>
> Т.п. Покинь-Сохой
>
> П.п. Покинь-Сохе

Answer (score 0):

А в правиле написано : если перед –а стоит согласная, то окончаниями падежей будут: -а, -ы, -е

Comment: Существительные с основой на **г, к, х** склоняются по образцу существительных первого школьного склонения на мягкий согласный. В родительном падеже у них окончание **и**.

Answer (score 0):

Склонение фамилии Соха по падежам

```
          мужской род женский род множественное число
```

именительный (Кто?) Соха    Соха       Сохы

родительный (Кого?) Сохы    Сохы       Сох

дательный (Кому?)   Сохе    Сохе        Сохам

винительный (Кого?) Соху    Соху        Сох

творительный (Кем?) Сохой   Сохой       Сохами

предложный (О ком?) Сохе    Сохе        Сохах

http://www.analizfamilii.ru/Sokha/skloneniye.html

Comment: Петро, зачем вы приводите эту ссылку? Я вам могу привести другую, где представлен тот вариант , который я привел. Существует правило, на основе которого нужно писать: **Сохи**, а не сох*ы*. 
 Прежде чем что-то писать, можно заглянуть в словарь.[Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/bts/)